# KnapSack dynamic programming in R with recursive function

Tags: r, recursion, knapsack-problem

I created this simple code in R to solve the Knapsack program with a recursive funtion

```
n <- c(0,1,2,3,4)
v <- c(10,40,30,50)
w <- c(5,4,6,3)
k <- 10


myfunction  <- function(n,k){
  if (n==0 | k==0){
  output <- 0
  } else if (w[i] > k) {
        output <- myfunction[i-1,w]
  } else {
        output <- max(v[i]+ myfunction(i-1, k-w[i]),myfunction(i-1,k))
      }
return(myfunction)
}
```

However, I don't get a value as an output, but the whole function. For example if I put in: 
    myfunction(4,10)

I don't get an value of 90, but the whole funtion typed out.

[image]

these are the values

Comment: You should use `return(output)` and not `return(myfunction)`. Also, you are using `i` in your function but is is not defined so the function has to be corrected.

Answer (score 6):

There were several errors beyond the ones pointed out by @etienne. Here's an annotated debugging session. First we fix the returned object:

```
> myfunction  <- function(n,k){
+   if (n==0 | k==0){
+   output <- 0
+   } else if (w[i] > k) {
+         output <- myfunction[i-1,w]
+   } else {
+         output <- max(v[i]+ myfunction(i-1, k-w[i]),myfunction(i-1,k))
+       }
+ return(output)
+ }
> myfunction(4,10)
Error in if (w[i] > k) { : argument is of length zero
```

Obviously neither w nor k are of length zero which suggests it must be `i`. (As also pointed out by etienne). Looking at your code it appears you actually intended `i` to be the index that decreased until the terminating condition was met. So replace `n` by `i` in the few instances where it appeared:

```
> myfunction  <- function(i,k){
+   if (i==0 | k==0){
+   output <- 0
+   } else if (w[i] > k) {
+         output <- myfunction[i-1,w]
+   } else {
+         output <- max(v[i]+ myfunction(i-1, k-w[i]),myfunction(i-1,k))
+       }
+ return(output)
+ }
> myfunction(4,10)
Error in myfunction[i - 1, w] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

So you also made the mistake of using square-brackets where parentheses (aka bracket in the non-US sections of the world) were needed:

```
> myfunction  <- function(i,k){
+   if (i==0 | k==0){
+   output <- 0
+   } else if (w[i] > k) {
+         output <- myfunction(i-1,w)
+   } else {
+         output <- max(v[i]+ myfunction(i-1, k-w[i]),myfunction(i-1,k))
+       }
+ return(output)
+ }
> myfunction(4,10)
[1] 90
```

Success, well, almost. Most of the warnings are because you used `|` instead of `||` in one of the conditionals:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (i == 0 | k == 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (w[i] > k) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (i == 0 | k == 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (i == 0 | k == 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In if (i == 0 | k == 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
6: In if (i == 0 | k == 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

So replace that instance with a logical `||`. To deal with the other warning that didn't seem to sabotage your logic, realize that `w[i]` is length-0 when `i == 0`, so add a logical clause in the conditional that first tests for that possibility and use the correct "double-AND-sign" ( `&&` ):

```
myfunction  <- function(i,k){
  if (i==0 || k==0){
  output <- 0
  } else if (length( w[i]) && w[i] > k) {
        output <- myfunction(i-1,w)
  } else {
        output <- max(v[i]+ myfunction(i-1, k-w[i]), myfunction(i-1,k))
      }
return(output)
}
```

Now you get:

```
> myfunction(4,10)
[1] 90
```